# AJAX is not handling server response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending file along with some data to backend which is written by flask. the backend is handling the request successfully but the ajax is not handling the response from the backend. Here my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#upload").click(function () {
    const title = $("#tutorial-title").val();
    const description = $("#tutorial-description").val();
    const file = $("#tutorial-file").prop("files")[0];
    const selectedOption = $("#course option:selected").val();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", title);
    formData.append("description", description);
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("category", selectedOption);

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/create",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
    })
      .done(function (response) {
        alert("Thank You!");
        window.location.replace("home.html");
        $("#form1").reset();
      })
      .fail(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert("error");
      });
  });
});
```

The backend is responding as it supposed to. Here are responses from backend.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2023 12:00:05] "POST /api/v1/create HTTP/1.1" 500 -

127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2023 12:00:49] "POST /api/v1/create HTTP/1.1" 201 -
```

I don't know where to go from here now.

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: 500 - means an error on the server side - show what /api/v1/create is doing - you have an error there

Comment: and why do you get two answers - there should be one

Comment: the two answers are response for different requests.

Comment: @mplungjan I am not see anything on the console cause, the form is reseting itself after click.

Comment: @WiatroBosy I am aware of the error, I wanna handle the response according to it. for example I wanna tell users to change their title if there is conflict of article in backend. the  response from the server is not a problem.

Comment: Check "preserve log" in the console settings

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        statusCode: {
            201: function() {
              alert('201 status code! user error');
            },
            500: function() {
              alert('500 status code! server error');
            }
        },
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/create",
      type: "POST",
      
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
    })
      .done(function (response) {
              console.error(response);

      })
      .fail(function (error, textStatus, code) {
        switch (code) {
            case 404:
               // Take action, 
               //referencing textStatus as needed.
               default:
                console.log('Sorry, error');
          }

      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

one of the possible solutions